# Package with multiple modules in different folders

Tags: python

I have a folder with sub-folders, each have an `__init__.py` file and a file named the same as the folder (say one folder's name is `module1` then I have a `module1.py` file inside). I appended the main folder in my path and I want the user to be able to import files typing just `import module1` and not `import module1.module1` as is working now.

Is it possible to accomplish this without uniting everything into one folder (keeping it divided to sub-folders) and without adding every sub-folder into the path (I have dozens of them)?

Comment: 'a file named the same as the folder' Why do you do that?

Comment: It would be a duplicate as the directory name is itself a module... If you want to do what you think, it might be easier to add your code to the `__init__.py` file (though this is not really standard, one usually use `import` to other files in the directory to achieve this).